# Does the orientation of the Ethernet magnetics matter?

Tags: voltage, transformer, ethernet, magnetics, common-mode

I've this [Ethernet magnetics transformer](https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/749013011A.pdf) connected between the PHY and the Connector?

Does the orientation of the magnetics with respect to the PHY matter? Meaning, should the common mode choke inside the magnetics be close to the ethernet connector or the ethernet PHY?

Can someone tell the reason what might happen if the magnetics is swapped 180deg?

Does it affect any ESD tests? Because I have one contact discharged test failed at 3kV? Can it be because of the transformer orientation swapping?

Answer (score 2):

Read the application notes for the PHY, transformer, and other related information.

The CMCs go on the media side.  Minimize stub length between PHY and transformer.

A "stub" is a length of transmission line that loads the signal without also carrying that signal to a load.  10/100BASE-T PHYs use a push-pull configuration, i.e. two N-MOSFETs sinking to GND on either side of a center-tapped transformer.  When a given transistor is driving the load, the other side is open-circuit and swings up by transformer action, its pin capacitance (and the stub consisting of the other half of the transformer winding, and trace and pin length) are momentarily dead weight.

As the bandwidth requirement is rather modest (62MHz), the maximum allowed stub length is also pretty long (~10s cm), so it's not a big deal in practice -- this is easily achieved in layout, even without minimizing the distance between PHY and magnetics.  Just something nice to have.

Comment: So, the CMC should be placed near the PHY and not near the connector ?

Comment: @Newbie The PCB traces to the connectors,the connectors themselves, and the cable all form a single continuous transmission line all the way to the far end transformer. Making those traces a bit longer just adds a few centimetres to a line that is already many metres long,so it doesn't matter. On the other hand,the traces between the transformer and the PHY are a separate,much shorter transmission line,where it makes a lot of difference if it's suddenly twice as long.

Comment: "Media" means cable, connector, etc.